# Create Tablespace in Remote Machine in Oracle

Tags: oracle, remote-server, tablespace

I want to create tablespace in remote machine where my oracle server exist,

I have admin privileges to both machines.

i tried something like this

```
create tablespace SampleSpace datafile '\\RemoteMachine\app\Administrator\oradata\orcl\SampleSpace.dbf' size 5M autoextend on next 10240K maxsize 8388640K;
```

But it is showing error like

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01119: error in creating database file
'\RemoteMachine\app\Administrator\oradata\orcl\SampleSpaxce.dbf
ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file.
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 5) Access is denied.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, Make sure whether you have read and write permissions to \RemoteMachine\app\Administrator\oradata\orcl folder